# How to obtain all subsequence combinations of a String (in Java, or C++ etc)

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

Let's say I've a string "12345" I should obtain all subsequence combinations of this string such as:

1. --> 1 2 3 4 5
2. --> 12 13 14 15 23 24 25 34 35 45
3. --> 123 124 125 234 235 345
4. --> 1234 1235 1245 1345 2345
5. --> 12345

Please note that I grouped them in different number of chars but not changed their order. I need a method/function does that.

Comment: Is the example supposed to be exhaustive? That is, is there another criteria for picking ordered subsets?

Comment: RC, sorry I'm editing it. There is no "6" at all...

Comment: You should try to figure it out on your own. These kind of exercises will help you become a good programmer.

Comment: @StackedCrooked: Then again, the sole purpose of this site is to be a forum for asking questions. Why discourage people from doing that?

Comment: Did outis answer solve your problem? It is really the best approach.

Comment: Why is this tagged with "genetic-algorithms" ?

Comment: @Amit: That does sound odd. T is right next to R on the keyboard, though: Maybe it was supposed to be "generic"?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You want a powerset. Here are all the questions on StackOverflow that mention [powersets](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22powerset%22) or [power sets](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22power+set%22).

Here is a basic implementation in python:

```
def powerset(s):
    n = len(s)
    masks = [1<<j for j in xrange(n)]
    for i in xrange(2**n):
        yield [s[j] for j in range(n) if (masks[j] & i)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for elem in powerset([1,2,3,4,5]):
        print elem
```

And here is its output:

```
[]
[1]
[2]
[1, 2]
[3]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[4]
[1, 4]
[2, 4]
[1, 2, 4]
[3, 4]
[1, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5]
[1, 5]
[2, 5]
[1, 2, 5]
[3, 5]
[1, 3, 5]
[2, 3, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 5]
[4, 5]
[1, 4, 5]
[2, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[1, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Notice that its first result is the empty set. Change the iteration from this `for i in xrange(2**n):` to this `for i in xrange(1, 2**n):` if you want to skip an empty set.

Here is the code adapted to produce string output:

```
def powerset(s):
    n = len(s)
    masks = [1<<j for j in xrange(n)]
    for i in xrange(2**n):
        yield "".join([str(s[j]) for j in range(n) if (masks[j] & i)])
```

---

Edit 2009-10-24

Okay, I see you are partial to an implementation in Java. I don't know Java, so I'll meet you halfway and give you code in C#:

```
    static public IEnumerable<IList<T>> powerset<T>(IList<T> s)
    {
        int n = s.Count;
        int[] masks = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            masks[i] = (1 << i);
        for (int i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++)
        {
            List<T> newList = new List<T>(n);
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                if ((masks[j] & i) != 0)
                    newList.Add(s[j]);
            yield return newList;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Someone downvoted this -- why? Because I returned to this and added code in C# (and not Java!) to do what the OP asked? Sheesh. Glad I went the extra mile.

Comment: Order could be important in the poster's sequence, and it might be that elements occur more than once. Thus, the power set may not really help that much.

Comment: @hughdbrown: The same thing happened with my answer. I can not realize the reason of downvote.

Comment: @PeterAllenWebb: Interesting speculation, but not actually requirements of the OP. Not sure where you got the idea that having elements occur more than once was something the OP wanted.

Answer (score 13):

The simplest algorithm for generating subsets of a set of size N is to consider all binary numbers using N bits. Each position in the number represents an element from the set. If a bit in the number is 1, the corresponding set element is in the subset, otherwise the element isn't in the subset. Since the bits in a number are ordered, this preserves the ordering of the original set.

References:

1. "[Efficiently Enumerating the Subsets of a Set](http://applied-math.org/subset.pdf)"; Loughry, Hemert and Schoofs
2. "[Generating Subsets](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/generating-subsets.shtml)"; Stony Brook Algorithm Repository

Comment: And it's worth pointing out that this same technique can easily be adapted to sequences, rather than sets. Each of the N bits would correspond to one of the N sequence members which you would either take or leave according to whether the bit is 0 or 1.

Comment: @whoever is downvoting: why? (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes). A sequence is basically a set of pairs, the first of which is an integer. As noted in the answer, the method preserves ordering, so if you start with a sequence, you get sequences.

Answer (score 11):

way way cleaner approach can be achieved through recursion as follows.

```
Public class StrManipulation{

    public static void combinations(String suffix,String prefix){
        if(prefix.length()<0)return;
        System.out.println(suffix);
        for(int i=0;i<prefix.length();i++)
         combinations(suffix+prefix.charAt(i),prefix.substring(i+1,prefix.length()));
    }

    public static void main (String args[]){
        combinations("","12345");
        }
}
```

Comment: can it be improved like using string builder or char array instead?

Answer (score 10):

In C++ given the following routine:

```
template <typename Iterator>
bool next_combination(const Iterator first, Iterator k, const Iterator last)
{
   /* Credits: Mark Nelson http://marknelson.us */
   if ((first == last) || (first == k) || (last == k))
      return false;
   Iterator i1 = first;
   Iterator i2 = last;
   ++i1;
   if (last == i1)
      return false;
   i1 = last;
   --i1;
   i1 = k;
   --i2;
   while (first != i1)
   {
      if (*--i1 < *i2)
      {
         Iterator j = k;
         while (!(*i1 < *j)) ++j;
         std::iter_swap(i1,j);
         ++i1;
         ++j;
         i2 = k;
         std::rotate(i1,j,last);
         while (last != j)
         {
            ++j;
            ++i2;
         }
         std::rotate(k,i2,last);
         return true;
      }
   }
   std::rotate(first,k,last);
   return false;
}
```

You can then proceed to do the following:

```
std::string s = "12345";
for(std::size_t i = 1; i <= s.size(); ++i)
{
   do
   {
      std::cout << std::string(s.begin(),s.begin() + i) << std::endl;
   }
   while(next_combination(s.begin(),s.begin() + i,s.end()));
}
```

Comment: Wow that sounds cool but terrifying. Cannot be any recursive or iterated answers? I don't know much about STL or C Iterators

Answer (score 8):

using python, the itertools module defines a combinations() method which does just what you need.

```
from itertools import *
list(combinations( '12345', 2 ))
```

will give you:

```
[('1', '2'), ('1', '3'), ('1', '4'), ('1', '5'), ('2', '3'), ('2', '4'), ('2', '5'), ('3', '4'), ('3', '5'), ('4', '5')]
```

Comment: Pretty great but I can't port it to Java since I don't know much about Python. There is no "combinations" function in Java.

Comment: +1 compensation vote, OP never explicitly wrote in the question why it shouldn't be in Python so it seems unfair to downvote a somewhat correct answer

Answer (score 4):

Java implementation of outis' answer, taking the input strings as args.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Combo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    for ( int i = 1; i <= (1<<(args.length))-1; i++ ) {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      for ( int j = 0; j < args.length; j++ ) {
        if ( (i & (1<<j)) != 0) {
          builder.append(args[j]);
        }
      }
      results.add(builder.toString());
    }
    System.out.println( results );
  }
}
```

Here's a run.

```
> javac Combo.java
> java Combo A B C
[A, B, AB, C, AC, BC, ABC]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following class for this (in Java):

```
class Combinations {

  String input;
  StringBuilder cur;

  private void next(int pos, int reminder) {
    cur.append(input.charAt(pos));

    if (reminder == 1) {
      System.out.println(cur);
    } else {
      for (int i = pos + 1; i + reminder - 1 <= input.length(); i++)
        next(i, reminder - 1);
    }
    cur.deleteCharAt(cur.length() - 1);
  }

  public void generate(String input) {
    cur = new StringBuilder();
    this.input = input;
    for (int length = 1; length <= input.length(); length++)
      for (int pos = 0; pos + length <= input.length(); pos++)
        next(pos, length);
  }
}
```

To run your example use the following code:

```
new Combinations().generate("12345");
```

The order of the output is the same as in example.
It does not require to store all subsets and then sort them to obtain the order you described.

Answer (score 1):

The code to generate all possible combinations of strings is given in java. The all possible combinations of string of length 4 is 2 ^ 4 (2 raised to the power 4). In general for a string of length n the possible combinations are 2 ^ n (2 raised to the power n). Hence the code:

```
    class Perms
    {
    public void permsOfString(String a)
      {
     int x = 1;

     /* 
          Computes 2^string length

     */

     for(int i = 0;i<a.length() ;i++)
     {
         x = x * 2;
     }
     /*
            Iterate through all the possible combinations using a binary value of the number

      */
     for(int i = 1 ;i<x;i++)
     {

         String binStr = Integer.toBinaryString(i); // Convert i to binary string 
         for(int j = binStr.length() ; j <  a.length() ;j++)
         {
             binStr = "0"+binStr; // left pad with 0s
         }
   /*loop through the binary string if a character at the string is '1' note the    index,then display the character of the given string with that index */

          for(int k = 0; k <binStr.length();k++)
          {
             if(binStr.charAt(k) == '0') continue;
             else
             {
                 System.out.print(a.charAt(k));
             }

          }
         System.out.println();

     }

    }
    public static void main(String[]s)
  {
Perms p = new Perms();
p.permsOfString("abcd");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Adrien Plisson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617699/how-to-obtain-all-subsequence-combinations-of-a-string-in-java-or-c-etc/1617818#1617818) shows how one retrieves all subsequences of a specified length in Python (for arbitrary sequence data types). The OP specifies that he works with strings, and that he wants *all* subsequences. Thus, using [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) we define:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> def subseq_combos(inp):
...     return (''.join(s) for r in range(len(inp) + 1) for s in combinations(inp, r))
... 
>>> list(subseq_combos('12345'))
['', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '12', '13', '14', '15', '23', '24', '25', '34', '35', '45', '123', '124', '125', '134', '135', '145', '234', '235', '245', '345', '1234', '1235', '1245', '1345', '2345', '12345']
```

(If the empty subsequence should be omitted, then use `range(1, len(inp) + 1))`.)

Comment: Pretty great but I can't port it to Java since I don't know much about Python.

Answer (score 0):

oops, wrong answer:

*Subsequences of a certain length in Python:*

```
def subseqs(seq, length):
    for i in xrange(len(seq) - length + 1):
        yield seq[i:i+length]
```

Used like this:

```
for each in subseqs("hello", 3):
    print each
```

prints:

```
hel
ell
llo
```

To generate all subsequences do this:

```
for i in xrange(len("hello")):
    for each in subseqs("hello", i + 1):
        print each
```

prints:

```
h
e
l
l
o
he
el
ll
lo
hel
ell
llo
hell
ello
hello
```

Mick.

Now I see, you wanted subsets, not sublists.

Answer (score 0):

**C implementation**

```
//Usage
combinations((char*)"",(char*)"12346897909787");


void combinations(char* suffix,char* prefix){
    if(NULL ==prefix || NULL == suffix){ return ;}
    int prefixLen = strlen(prefix);
    printf("\n[%s]",suffix);
    int slen  = strlen(suffix);
    char* s   = (char*)malloc(slen+2);
    s[slen+1] = '\0';
    for(int i=0;i<prefixLen;i++){
        strcpy(s,suffix);
        s[slen]  = prefix[i];
        int npfl = prefixLen-(i+1);
        char* p  = (char*) malloc(npfl+1);
        p[npfl]  = '\0';
        strcpy(p,prefix+i+1);
        combinations(s,p);
        free(p);
    }
    free(s);
}
```

Comment: For C, you would probably want an iterative version instead; let the user handle memory management.

Answer (score 0):

C++ solution:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int sub[10];

void next(int max, int length) {

    int pos = length - 1;

    //find first digit that can be increased
    while(pos >= 0)
    {
        if(sub[pos] == max - (length - 1 - pos))
            pos--;

        else
            break;
    }

        sub[pos]++; //increase digit

        //update other digits
        for(int a = pos+1; a < length; a++)
            sub[a] = sub[a-1] + 1;

}

int main()
{
    string word;
    cin >> word; 

    int max = word.length() - 1; //max value


    for(int n=1; n <= max+1; n++)
    {

        cout << n << "\n----\n";

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            sub[i] = i;
        }

        for(int a = 0; ; a++)
        {               
            for(int b=0; b < n; b++)
                cout << word[sub[b]];

            cout << '\n';

            if(sub[0] == max - (n - 1))
                break;

            else
                next(max, n); //maximum value and last position
        }   

        cout << '\n';

    }   


    return 0;
 }
> for input :Sigma
> output is
1
----
s
i
g
m
a

2
----
si
sg
sm
sa
ig
im
ia
gm
ga
ma

3
----
sig
sim
sia
sgm
sga
sma
igm
iga
ima
gma

4
----
sigm
siga
sima
sgma
igma

5
----
sigma
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Sub {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          String str="ADDIS";
          Sub.DisplaySubsequence( str.toCharArray(), 
          str.toCharArray().length,0 );
     }
     public static void DisplaySubsequence(char[] set, int n, int index){
         
        if(n>index){
            
                String x =String.valueOf(set[index]);
                System.out.println(x);
                String concat=x;
                for(int j=index+1; j<n; j++){
                        concat=concat.concat(String.valueOf(set[j]));
                        System.out.println(concat);
                 }
                 DisplaySubsequence(set, n,index+1);
         }
         
            return 0;
         
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).