# Permutation Generation

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, permutation

Some members of my team were discussing password storage and general security issues today. Anyway, the discussion briefly touched upon how quick GPU-accelerated brute-force attacks are compared to the traditional CPU-only implementations.

This got me interested, so I decided to play around with some code. Since I've never written anything like this before, I decided to write a simple (CPU-only) brute-forcer. My initial implementation dealt with a fixed length (4 digit) password. For testing purposes, I implemented it a la:

```
for(char a = '0'; a <= '9'; ++a)
{
  for(char b = '0'; b <= '9'; ++b)
  {
    for(char c = '0'; c <= '9'; ++c)
    {
      for(char d = '0'; d <= '9'; ++d)
      {
        candidate[0] = a; candidate[1] = b;
        candidate[2] = c; candidate[3] = d;

        // Test 'candidate'...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works well, but is obviously inflexible. I attempted to generalize the above to handle any password length but have failed to do so. For some reason, I can't get my head around the logic that these brute-forcers use to run through 1-n character possibilities given an "alphabet".

Is there some common algorithm that allows you to accomplish this? Any examples welcome.

Comment: The concept you are looking for is called [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) :)

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/q/3183469/21727

Comment: the problem is that you should have n nested loop, but n is known only at runtime... =/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to obtain all subsequence combinations of a String (in Java, or C++ etc)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617699/how-to-obtain-all-subsequence-combinations-of-a-string-in-java-or-c-etc)

Answer (score 0):

Search engines are your friends :)
[C++ Brute force example](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread50604.html)

(Scroll down a little bit..)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Iterative Version....The following works only for lowercase, but can easily be modified....

```
public static String nextLexographicWord(String txt)
{
    char [] letters = txt.toCharArray();
    int l = letters .length - 1;
    while(l >= 0)
    {
        if(letters[l] == 'z')
            letters[l] = 'a';
        else
        {
            letters[l]++;
            break;
        }
        l--;
    }
    if(l < 0) return 'a' + (new String(letters));
    return new String(letters); 
}
```