# How to make a combination list in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5

I want to make a list like this:

```
seq = [1,2,3]
\# implementation
print(result) \# [[1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [2], [2,3], [3]]
```

Comment: Have a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617699/how-to-obtain-all-subsequence-combinations-of-a-string-in-java-or-c-etc The question is for Java, but the first reply also shows the algorithm in python. What you want is the powerset.

Comment: So, do I have to make an original powerset function to eliminate a discontinuous element like [1,3] from a powerset?

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools combination : https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

You can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8371891/4997158) for more details

Comment: I know itertools, but I don't want to make a discontinuous element like [1,3].

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could find a solution by myself:

```
N = 3
print([list(range(i, j)) for i in range(1,N+2) for j in range(i+1,N+2)])
```

or,

```
N = 3
lis = [list(range(i + 1, j + 1)) for (i, j) in itertools.combinations(list(range(N + 1)), 2)]
print(lis)
```

Thank you!